# JavaScript Math Expression Yields Different Results

Tags: javascript, math

The following is a line I have in my Javascript code. It outputs -5108024 and some change when `sqftVal = 2828` and `bathsVal = 3.5`.

```
out.value = -6932000 + 221400 * Math.log(sqftVal) + 637.2*Math.exp(bathsVal) + 51640;
```

However, when I manually type this in my calculator, I get roughly -5099721 and some change. I get the same result in `R`. Why does JavaScript mess up the math, and what can I do to fix this?

Calculator/R input:
`-6932000 + 221400 * ln(2828) + 637.2 * e^(3.5) + 51640 = -5099721.073`

I don't believe this is a floating point error because as I add more terms, the difference becomes fairly large.

Plus, everything was matching up until I added the fourth term (`+51640`) which made no sense to me.

Comment: Could floating point errors be that off though?? @Yousaf

Comment: When I run `var sqftVal = 2828; var bathsVal = 3.5; -6932000 + 221400 * Math.log(sqftVal) + 637.2*Math.exp(bathsVal) + 51640;` in a console, I get `-5099721.073030476`...

Comment: @Yousaf No I don't believe it is floating points.

Comment: @HereticMonkey do you see anything different with the way I did it? I get that number in a R console, but not when I run my Javascript program.

Comment: I literally copied and pasted the code from the question into the console, slapped a couple of `var`s and semicolons in there to make it executable, and ran it.

Comment: Thanks everyone for their help! I was accidentally reading a float as an int which was floating my calculations off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some other code that is interfering with your values or something, because the code shown does not produce the value you report.

```js
var sqftVal = 2828; 
var bathsVal = 3.5; 
var value = -6932000 + 221400 * Math.log(sqftVal) + 637.2*Math.exp(bathsVal) + 51640;
console.log(value);
```